# DFA state transition table compression

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization, sparse-matrix, transition, dfa

I want to write Compiler for the first time and my reference is 'Compilers Principles,Techniques and Tools'. for the lexical design I wrote FA of my language tokens and now I want to write C# code from state transition table but it is a 40 X 30 matrix with just 50 entries in this matrix ! I want to compress this sparse matrix ! there is a method in the book which said:

> There is a more subtle data structure that allows us to combine the
>   speed of array access with the compression of lists with defaults. We
>   may think of this structure as four arrays, as suggested in Fig.
>   3.66.5 The base array is used to determine the base location of the entries for state s, which are located in the next and check arrays.
>   The default array is used to determine an alternative base location if
>   the check array tells us the one given by base[s] is invalid. To
>   compute nextState(s, a), the transition for state s on input a, we
>   examine the next and check entries in location l = base[s]+ a, where
>   character a is treated as an integer, presumably in the range 0 to
>   127. If check[l] = s, then this entry is valid, and the next state for state s on input a is next[l]. If check[l] != s, then we determine
>   another state t = default[s] and repeat the process as if t were the
>   current state. More formally, the function nextstate is defined as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> int nextState(s, a) {
> if ( check[base[s] + a] = s ) return next[base[s] + a];
> else return nextState(default[s], a);
> }
> ```

I don't understand what is this four array consist of ? can any one explain for me ? do you have another simple algorithm for me which optimize my code for sparse compression?I know CSR compression but I don't know how should I use them for writing nextState(s,a) in my C# code !Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 12):

Let's say there are six input symbols: the letters *a b c d e*, and EOF. Let's say we want our language to contain seven strings: *ace add bad bed bee cab dad* (and each must be terminated by EOF).

The simplest way to store a transition table for the DFA is as a two-dimensional array `simpleNext`. One axis is the state number, and the other axis is the input symbol number. When the FA is in state `s` and sees symbol `a`, it moves to state `simpleNext[s][a]`.

Here's a `simpleNext` transition table for a DFA that recognizes our example strings:

```
st#   a  b  c  d  e EOF
  0   0  0  0  0  0  0
  1   2  3  4  5  0  0
  2   0  0 16 17  0  0
  3  11  0  0  0 12  0
  4   9  0  0  0  0  0
  5   6  0  0  0  0  0
  6   0  0  0  7  0  0
  7   0  0  0  0  0  8
  8   0  0  0  0  0  0
  9   0 10  0  0  0  0
 10   0  0  0  0  0  8
 11   0  0  0 15  0  0
 12   0  0  0 13 14  0
 13   0  0  0  0  0  8
 14   0  0  0  0  0  8
 15   0  0  0  0  0  8
 16   0  0  0  0 19  0
 17   0  0  0 18  0  0
 18   0  0  0  0  0  8
 19   0  0  0  0  0  8
```

State 0 is the error state. If the FA gets here, it read some symbol while in a state that has no transition from that state. State 8 (the only other all-zero row) is the only accepting state.

The problem here is that `simpleNext` is size `|S| × ||` (number of states times number of symbols) = 120. For a real DFA (as found in language parsers), with many more states and symbols, it would be much larger. Not too large for RAM these days, but probably wasting a lot of L1 cache lines.  Most states don't have transitions for most symbols, so a large fraction of the table is set to 0 (the error state).

We'd like a way to store the transition table in much less space, while still letting us access it very quickly.

Let's explore a similar, but simpler version of the compression technique described in the book.

Let's line up the rows of the table a little differently. Start with rows 0 and 1:

```
  0   0  0  0  0  0  0
  1   2  3  4  5  0  0
```

Then shift row 2 over until its non-zero entries (16 and 17) have only zeros above them:

```
  0   0  0  0  0  0  0
  1   2  3  4  5  0  0
  2         0  0 16 17  0  0
```

Now shift row 3 over until its non-zero entries (11 and 12) have only zeros above them:

```
  0   0  0  0  0  0  0
  1   2  3  4  5  0  0
  2         0  0 16 17  0  0
  3                    11  0  0  0 12  0
```

(Note that we have to pretend that each row has an infinite number of zeros appended to it.)

Repeat with the remaining rows, one by one. Finally you have this:

```
  0   0  0  0  0  0  0
  1   2  3  4  5  0  0
  2         0  0 16 17  0  0
  3                    11  0  0  0 12  0
  4                        9  0  0  0  0  0
  5                           6  0  0  0  0  0
  6                     0  0  0  7  0  0
  7                     0  0  0  0  0  8
  8   0  0  0  0  0  0
  9                                    0 10  0  0  0  0
 10                           0  0  0  0  0  8
 11                                    0  0  0 15  0  0
 12                                       0  0  0 13 14  0
 13                                       0  0  0  0  0  8
 14                                          0  0  0  0  0  8
 15                                             0  0  0  0  0  8
 16                                                   0  0  0  0 19  0
 17                                                         0  0  0 18  0  0
 18                                                      0  0  0  0  0  8
 19                                                         0  0  0  0  0  8
```

Now write down the amount by which we moved each row:

```
st# off
  0   0   0  0  0  0  0  0
  1   0   2  3  4  5  0  0
  2   2         0  0 16 17  0  0
  3   6                    11  0  0  0 12  0
  4   7                        9  0  0  0  0  0
  5   8                           6  0  0  0  0  0
  6   6                     0  0  0  7  0  0
  7   6                     0  0  0  0  0  8
  8   0   0  0  0  0  0  0
  9  11                                    0 10  0  0  0  0
 10   8                           0  0  0  0  0  8
 11  11                                    0  0  0 15  0  0
 12  12                                       0  0  0 13 14  0
 13  12                                       0  0  0  0  0  8
 14  13                                          0  0  0  0  0  8
 15  14                                             0  0  0  0  0  8
 16  15                                                   0  0  0  0 19  0
 17  16                                                         0  0  0 18  0  0
 18  17                                                      0  0  0  0  0  8
 19  18                                                         0  0  0  0  0  8
```

Now collapse the rows into one row, overwriting zeros with non-zeros. Keep the offsets as a separate array:

```
    index  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
nextState  2  3  4  5 16 17 11  9  6  7 12  8 10  8 15 13 14  8  8  8 19 18  8  8

     state#  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
  stateBase  0  0  2  6  7  8  6  6  0 11  8 11 12 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

At this point, we can use these two arrays to find any non-zero value from the original array. For state `s` and symbol number `i`, if `simpleNext[s][i]` was non-zero, then the same value is in `nextState[stateBase[s] + i]`.

The only remaining problem with this scheme is that we don't know which values from the original table were zero. We can fix that by adding another array, `checkState`, parallel to `nextState`. For each element of `nextState`, the corresponding element of `checkState` tells us which state the `nextState` was originally copied from:

```
     index  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 nextState  2  3  4  5 16 17 11  9  6  7 12  8 10  8 15 13 14  8  8  8 19 18  8  8
checkState  1  1  1  1  2  2  3  4  5  6  3  7  9 10 11 12 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

Now, for some state `s` and symbol number `i`, we can see whether `nextState[stateBase[s] + i]` belongs to state `s`, or whether the original table had a zero there for state `s` and symbol `i`:

```
if (checkState[stateBase[s] + i] == s) {
    return nextState[stateBase[s] + i];
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

The original `simpleNext` table contains 6 * 20 = 120 values. The compressed table (the combination of `stateBase`, `nextState` and `checkState`) contains 2 * 23 + 20 = 66 numbers. For typical DFAs (as found in language parsers), with many more states and symbols, the compression ratio is much better.

In a real implementation, I'd probably store `nextState` and `checkState` as a single array of structures, e.g.

```
typedef struct {
    int nextState;
    int checkState;
} TableEntry;

TableEntry table[NUM_ENTRIES];
```

Anyway, the compression scheme described in the book is a more complicated variation of this. It's getting late for me so I'm going to leave off here but I'll try to come back tomorrow and explain how the book's scheme differs from what I've explained above.

Comment: Then why do we need a 'default' array? How does it help and how we could construct it?

Comment: Look at the `simpleNext` table (the first table in my answer). See how lots of rows are similar to each other? E.g. row 5 is almost exactly the same as row 0 (they only differ in column 0). The `defaults` array takes advantage of that similarity. When you get to row 5 during compression, you only store the entries of row 5 that are different from the corresponding entries of row zero. Then you set the `defaults` entry for row 5 to 0. When parsing, the matcher (by looking in `defaults`) knows to use row 0's entries if it can't find an entry it needs for row 5.

Comment: Even better, row 10 is identical to row 7. So the compresser doesn't have to store any entries specific to row 10. It just stores 7 in the `defaults` table for row 10, and when the matcher needs an entry for row 10, it will always end up using row 7's entries.

Comment: This is such a helpful explanation, thank you @robmayoff. I'm not sure I understand the gist of the last paragraph of Section 3.9.8, which says, "While we may not be able to choose base values so that no next-check entries remain unused, experience has shown that the simple strategy of assigning base values to states in turn, and assigning each base[s] value the lowest integer so that the special entries for state s are not previously occupied utilizes little more space than the minimum possible."

Comment: Does this mean that if states 1 and 2 are similar so that state 1 has entries 5, 6, 7 and state 2 has entries 5, 8, 7, then the base value for 2 is calculated by offsetting 8?.